# Getting user provided data out of a database and into R

Tags: r

I am creating the function below. The purpose is to take in a user provided variable list from an Access database for use in other functions. I would like users to provide a list separated by commas. I have tried several different methods to loop through the provided variable list but cannot get it to operate correctly. My for loop is problematic.

```
f.extractVariables<-
  structure(function 
(dbPath,dbName,table,variables
   ){
# LOAD LIBRARIES
require(RODBC)
require(xlsx)

setwd(dbPath)
db <- odbcConnectAccess2007(dbName)

for (i in 0:length(variables))
{
dataCollection <- sqlQuery(db, 'SELECT table.variables[[i]]
                        FROM table;')
}

odbcClose(db)
)
}, ex=function(){
    #Positive Test to retrieve specified variables from specified location
    dbPath = 'z:/sites/'
    dbName = 'oysterSites.accdb'
    table  = 'tblDataSiteOysterSamplingPlan'
    variables= (nwLon, nwLat, neLon, neLat)
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to use a loop here. You can build your query using `paste`:

```
variables= "nwLon, nwLat, neLon, neLat"  ##  user input string
```

If use give a list a variables:

```
variables= c("nwLon", "nwLat", "neLon", "neLat")
variables = paste(variables,collapse=",")
```

Then you build the query as :

```
query <- paste(paste("SELECT" ,variables),
"FROM table",sep='\n')
cat(query)
# SELECT nwLon, nwLat, neLon, neLat
# FROM table
```

Comment: Probably also worth commenting on the attempt to use 0-based indexing, even though it's not need with this solution.

Comment: I realize now that I need to clarify that I need the data from the database. The user provides the list of variables they want and the function retrieves the data. For example, after requesting nwLon the user should be able to type "nwLon" in the command line and that data should be visible, ready for analysis, or plotting.